# Php PDO search string as Google or order by best match

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo, google-search-api

My pdo query I want best match result

```
/* Results */
      function getResults(){
      $q=$GLOBALS['q'];
      $p=$GLOBALS['p'];
      $start=($p-1)*10;
      if($q!=null){
      $starttime = microtime(true);
      $sql=$GLOBALS['dbh']->prepare("SELECT 
                                 * FROM `shop` 
                                WHERE `title` LIKE :q 
                                OR `add` LIKE :q 
                                OR `about` LIKE :q 
                                OR `owner` LIKE :q 
                                OR `spe` LIKE :q 
                                OR `cat_nm` LIKE :q 
                                OR `sub_nm` LIKE :q");
      $sql->bindValue(":q", "%$q%");
      $sql->execute();
      $trs=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My query search only full match text example:

[check here](https://www.asklocalinfo.com/search)

I want search result like as google help me.

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: issue is i want order by best match